# What's the difference between "scarce", "rare" and "uncommon"?

Tags: word-choice

According to a dictionary, all these words are quite synonymous. Is there any subtle difference in meaning?

I consulted the Free dictionary and found that:

> **scarce**: Hard to find; absent or rare.
>
> **rare**:  Infrequently occurring; uncommon.
>
> **uncommon**:  Not common; rare.

Answer (score 4):

All three talk about frequency of occurrence for *something* within a population of *things*

> rare

does not occur as often as

> uncommon

does not occur as often as

> common
>   ordinary

"scarce" has more of an absolute meaning of "hard to find or obtain" sometimes do to very high demand or very low supply

> Available tickets to the playoff finals are very *scarce* since everyone wants to go.
>
> Snow in the Sahara is *uncommon* and would be a *rare* occurrence.
>   Potable water in the Sahara is *scarce*.

If you say *something* is "uncommonly good" it means it is "more than very good", however, if you say *something* is "rarely good" it means it is "not often good" or "usually bad".

Answer (score 1):

When my son was in kindergarten he told me *rare* is a city word you use to discribe art, wine and jewels and *scarce* is a country word you use to describe food and water.

Answer (score 0):

"Scarce" is something that is rare, compared to what is needed. In the zoo, the food for the elephants might be scarce, but they still have a lot of it - just not enough considering the size of an elephants belly. Diamonds are rare, but we have enough of them. "Uncommon" is usually related to being different from a common variant; triplets are uncommon, because single births and twins are much more common.

So all three words imply "rare", but "scarce" and "uncommon" have additional meanings.

Answer (score 0):

In writing my latest book, I wanted to describe the relative availability of a selection of certain military artifacts. I "graded" the words in ascending order of difficulty to find: "Uncommon" being the most likely to be encountered, then "scarce", then "rare" to describe the items least likely to be found.