# Do uncommon and rare both have same meaning?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, spoken-english, learning

"Do 'uncommon' and 'rare' both have the same meaning, and can one replace the other in a sentence?"

Can you explain what is the correct usage.

> Uncommon (of an event, situation, or condition) not occurring very
> often:
>
> Rare not seen, happening, or experienced often.

Also, similar question found at [ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108956/…,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108956)

Does meaning vary / change when use with living versus non living objects?

Is there any other way to improve the question?

Comment: This question has already been asked here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108956/whats-the-difference-between-scarce-rare-and-uncommon

Comment: Yes. Almost same.

Comment: I've flagged this question to be reopened. It *is* a duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108956/whats-the-difference-between-scarce-rare-and-uncommon, but my feeling is that both the question, the three answers (full disclosure, one of which is by me, including the accepted answer) and the comments are of significantly higher quality than the older post, and therefore worth keeping. I don't actually agree with the level of certainty indicated by the most popular answer provided on the older post, and none was accepted by the OP.

Comment: Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?

Comment: See the FAQ: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, there are two completely contradictory answers, one saying they're complete synonyms, and one saying 'uncommon' is 'more common' than 'rare'. One has received a downvote for being 'misleading'.

My instinct was that @Jaime was right, but on reflection I realised that as a negative form of 'common', uncommon might acquire slightly different meanings *according to context*. However, this would be the exception to the general rule. I can't think of a sentence off the top of my head where the difference is significant. You probably need to use both words in close proximity before any distinction would be relevant.

For instance:

> The crested newt has become uncommon in recent years, but is not yet considered rare.

But in both my example and @Biblasia's, 'rare' is being used in a more technical and scientific sense of 'rare animals', and it's the context of the usage that creates a distinction in meaning, not the words themselves.

So I actually think both contradictory answers *can* be correct, in some circumstances. However, I think as a general rule of thumb, you can treat 'uncommon' and 'rare' as exact synonyms, and therefore Jaime is more correct.

Edit:
I plead guilty to not having checked the dictionary first, but, the 2022 edition of the [American Heritage dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=uncommon) says this:

> un·com·mon (ŭn-kŏmən) adj.
> un·com·mon·er, un·com·mon·est
>
> 1. Not common; **rare**.
> 2. Wonderful; remarkable. un·common·ly adv. un·common·ness n.
>
> rare 1 (râr) adj. rar·er, rar·est
>
> 1. Infrequently occurring; **uncommon**: a rare event; a plant that is rare in this region.
> 2. Excellent; extraordinary: a rare sense of honor.
> 3. Thin in density; rarefied: rare air.

It seems to me that the dictionary considers Jaime's answer closer to the normally-understood truth than Biblasia's.

Comment: This is an interesting discussion. To me, when I hear "uncommon", I automatically think "so it's sometimes happening, although it's not very easy to see them", but when I hear "rare", what I think is "oh, it's almost not happening".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As far as I can tell, they're more or less complete synonyms.

Although ... 'rare' can sometimes (only sometimes) carry a positive nuance about it (in the sense of 'precious'), while 'uncommon' tends to be more neutral.

Comment: I have downvoted your answer Jaime, as it's misleading.  It's a good idea to check dictionary meanings rather than just to offer an opinion.

Comment: @RonaldSole I just checked a dictionary, and Jaime's answer seems pretty much bang-on to me.

Comment: I disagree that they are synonyms in common usage.  I don't think a dictionary definition can tell you everything about a word's meaning.

Comment: @fred2 Exceptionally clever people are uncommon; geniuses are rare. There is a distinct difference of degree that you will find, for example in the classification of diseases, and that should be respected in a serious dialogue, as opposed to informal conversation.

Comment: Does meaning vary / change when use with living versus non living objects?

Comment: @RonaldSole I checked the dictionary meaning, of course, before posting my answer. Merriam-Webster, which gives "uncommon" as its principle synonym for "rare".

Comment: @strangdon So we penalise users on this site for not checking the dictionary, and then when they do we tell them that the dictionary doesn't contain all the information they need? For the purposes of an English language learners site, I think we have to go with the generally understood/dictionary defined sense of a word, and not definitions that are matters of opinion.

Comment: @RonaldSole. All I can say is that "Exceptionally clever people are rare; geniuses are even more uncommon" works just as well from my perspective. I accept their may be a technical sense I'm unaware of, but I don't think there is in general speech.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are speaking of a species of animal.  We might select its status from a list like this:

- ubiquitous (exist everywhere)
- common
- uncommon
- rare
- endangered
- extinct (no longer exist)

As you should see, "rare" is less common than "uncommon."  They are not equal in meaning.

Comment: I think this is more general than just animals, but agree that something that is *uncommon* is probably more likely to be encountered than *rare*.